# BottomSheetDialog dims background being used in ViewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I have a fragment that I want to display as an embedded fragment in a ViewPager and as a Bottom Sheet. I followed this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#DialogOrEmbed and created a DialogFragment

```
    private val mViewModel: CardPricesViewModel by viewModels()

    private val binding by viewBinding(FragmentCardDetailPricesBinding::inflate)


    companion object {
        // This is the same value as the navArg name so that the SavedStateHandle can acess from either
        const val ARG_SKU_IDS = "skuIds"

        fun newInstance(skus: List<Long>?) =
            CardDetailPricesFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putLongArray(ARG_SKU_IDS, skus?.toLongArray())
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

However, when it gets inflated in a ViewPager the background dims as though it is a BottomSheetDialogFragment

[image]

However, when I manually do it with

```
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(binding.cardPricesFragmentContainer.id, cardDetailPricesFragment)
            .commit()
```

It works fine. I see that the FragmentStateAdapter uses FragmentViewHolders instead of the using transactions directly (?), so I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I see that onCreateDialog() is being called, so if I call dismiss() after onViewCreated(), it works properly, but I am not sure if this a workaround

Comment: It seems like a blank dialog was being created, causing the dimming. After looking into the source code I found this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#setShowsDialog(boolean). showsDialog gets set to false automatically when you inflate it into a container view, so it display the dialog, hence no dimming. In the case of using it in ViewPager2 seems like you will have to manually set it to false

Answer (score -1):

After some digging, I found the [`DialogFragment.setShowsDialog(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#setShowsDialog(boolean)) method that you can use to disable the dialog being created.